# How do I delete just one specific auto suggested URL from android chrome browser

Tags: chrome-for-android

I would like to remove only one particular URL from auto suggestions in my mobile (android) chrome browser. U know how embarrassing it gets sometime when u forget to use incognito mode and don't know how to delete the auto suggested website. The shift+delete can't work with mobile as highlight option is not possible. Also I would like to keep all my other browser suggestions in tact.

Anyone can help? Please...

Answer (score 4):

Holding down a suggestion will ask the user if it should be removed from the browsing history, and therefore removed from the suggestions.

[image: Screenshot]

If holding down on a suggestion does not bring up the prompt, then make sure you have typed some matching text in the URL bar. The default suggestions for an empty URL bar, or for a newly selected URL bar, do not respond to the press & hold in the same way (Experienced on Chrome 52.)

I tested this on Chrome for Android 51.0.2704.81 and Chrome Beta for Android 52.0.2743.49.

Comment: Ace! But this only works for me if I type in a bit of text that matches the URL that I want to remove. Normally if I select the URL bar or clear it then there are default suggestions which do not respond to the click & hold in this way. Typing some matching text brings up the URLs in a way which does work though.

Comment: Great advice but it seems very hit-and-miss whether holding the text will bring up the choice. Some links seem quite resistant to deletion.